# Move only specific commits or do branching?

Tags: git

I have a git repo @ origin.
A LIVE clone with live project on server.
A DEV clone with development version on local.

I keep working on DEV repo and have committed so many times. But live repo is still the same position. I plan to do `pull` on live server when development is done.

Problem is, I have to go live with one change right away. It may be a single or multiple commits on DEV somewhere in middle of commit history.

Is it possible to get only those needed commits pulled on live repo. Still making sure that when development is done; everything is pulled over to live repo without breaking anything.

If it's not possible, I've another approach in mind. That is, create a branch on live. Do required changes on it (again of-course) on same files (which are updated on dev repo now). And push that branch to origin, then pull it to dev and merge it there with master. How can I make sure that when finally development is over, nothing is broken and I go live smoothly.

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand the [git rebasing](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing) concept.

You have 2 options:

- Rebase you dev branch to isolate the target commits and move them to
  the bottom of everything else on dev (but on top of the newest common
  commit you have on both dev and production), then you can cut a
  branch with the head of the target commits. [You can use `git rebase -i live/master` for that]
- Cherry-pick the target commits one-by-one to a new branch [with `git cherry-pick COMMIT-ID`], then you can merge that new branch to both live and dev.

Comment: This sounds much more like a job for cherry-pick than rebasing.